# Properties of logical systems: which field study it?

Tags: logic, book-recommendation, formal-systems

Throughout my study of a [paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-33205-5_2) (speacially p. 30) I had seen properties of logical systems, and its criteria, whose I'm not acquainted with. Some of them are: being a Tarskian logic, monotonic finitary, structural, standard. My question is what field does this kind of categorization and what are good some recommended readings.

*Page in question
[image]

Comment: It is very difficult evaluating the quality of the linked paper, as it requires the purchase of the article, or the book in which it's contained. However, a good clue when you find yourself asking about a field that studies another field...is the term "meta...".  I would suggest you widen your exposure to logical systems; also start a broad search of Wikipedia and references listed there about the "foundations" of mathematics.

Comment: Honestly, it is very difficult to answer your question because you provided very little in the way of the context in which you encountered the article, what background you have in logic and/or mathematical logic?  There's a lot we'd need to knw before being able to recommend readings, and/or books.  You might want to explore Wikipedia's entry on Philosophy of Logic, e.g.  But of most importance, I'd like to stress that you ought **never** rely on a single survey or discussion about various systems of logic, etc.

Comment: [Algebraic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequence-algebraic/). See also [Abstract algebraic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebraic_logic).

Comment: I had tryed 'metalogic' but it doesn't seem to be (or I was unable to reach at) a defined field. About my background, I know classical propositional and predicate logic at undergraduate level. Also, I have some notion of set theory and a little of various subjects that are presented in Peter Smith's "Introduction to Gödel's Theorem". As I'm making my transition from philosophy to serious logic, I have saw a number of uses of properties and definitions without reference to its fields. 
Also, I could add a page example from the article given that just one page shouldn't violate copyright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the topic see :

> [Algebraic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequence-algebraic/) as well as [Abstract algebraic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebraic_logic).

For refernces :

- J.Michael Dunn and Gary Hardegree, [Algebraic Methods in Philosophical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=-AokWhbILUIC&printsec=frontcover) (2001)
- Ryszard Wójcicki, [Theory of logical calculi : basic theory of consequence operations](https://books.google.it/books?id=TXfoCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1988).